# Self-Deprecating and Ironic Humour

Tags: single-word-requests

I once found a word on the Internet, but unfortuantely didn't write it down, and have yet to rediscovered it.   The word perfectly describes the type of self-depricating, ironic , cutting but happy, wise type of humour that exists within my family and literary friends.  e.g. A comment on a spate of gang killings recently: **"One solution would be to supply them with free amunition and send the Police on holiday for a week... but that's just me."** .The self-deprecating humour is in the phrase  "but that's just me" intimates that you self describe that you are a heartless individual worthy of contempt **BUT** that actually is the way you feel about the situation. Does anyone know what the word is..? It sort of like Iconoclast or Black Ironist but, anyway it's been around since Victorian times "Coach Wit" and all that. There is such a word to describe the attitude-humour.... Someone must know it...? Thanks..!

Comment: To me, this is straight sarcasm. As though the opinion is novel: I don't appreciate the rudeness, but that's just me (no it's not.)

Comment: For single word requests, please give a sample sentence to show how the word is used.

Comment: Hi there (Horace here) New to this public forum and thanks for your replies.  H'mmm.... sample sentance....? No, all I can say is that there is a word that defines people who possess that type humour and wit. They self-depricate and often finish with "but that's just me" intimating, with humour,  that this is the obvious and logical point of view. However, Yosef, it seems like to understand the "but that's just me" ...no it's not just me.

Comment: I wouldn’t call that self-deprecating either.  Now, *“One solution would be ….   because that’s the best my feeble brain can come up with”* would be self-deprecating.

Comment: I agree with Jim. "If it were up to me, I would do X—but luckily it isn't" is another truly self-deprecating formulation. Following up a radical suggestion (humorous or not) with "but that's just me" might be a way to suggest that the radical idea is impracticable not because it is extreme or offensive or inhumane or counterproductive, but because everyone in a position to actually adopt it is constrained by political calculation or artificial and self-defeating notions of social etiquette. That is, "but that's just me" might imply "but I'm a truth teller (unlike the powers that be)."

Comment: "What a comeuppance for my sins, to be exiled to Paris. Where I shall die as I have always lived.... beyond me means" Oscar Wilde.  ... there's a term for it...?

Comment: "Those who pay their Hotel bill are soon forgotten" Oscar Wilde.

Comment: 'But that's just me' is a modal pragmatic marker, a comment clause reducing the level of confidence the hearer might reasonably afford the actual statement.

Comment: The two Oscar Wilde quotes noted in your comments above might fairly be described as "wry," which has three meanings, according to _Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary_ (2003): "**1 :** having a bent or twisted shape or condition {a _wry_ smile}; _also_ : turned abnormally to one side {a _wry_ neck} **2 :** WRONGHEADED [in the sense "marked by perversity : contrary to sound judgment"] **3 :**  cleverly and often ironically or grimly humorous." Definition 3 is the one that fits here—as it specifically invokes the twist in Wilde's observations. A harsher term would be "acerbic."

Answer (score 1):

One candidate is *sardonic*

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sardonic)
>
> sardonic, adjective
>
> humorous in an unkind way that shows you do not respect someone or something

Or Collins has

> [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sardonic)
>
> If you describe someone as sardonic, you mean their attitude to people or things is humorous but rather critical.

A slight shift of meaning with more humour in it is provided by *wry*

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wry)
>
> showing that you find a bad or difficult situation slightly amusing:

Comment: Thanks Anton. Yes, Sardonic or Satrirical is very close. I think perhaps the "but that's just me"  is satirical. However, I'm still convinced there's another term that means to use self-deprecating humour e.g.  " but of course I voted for him... which seemed like a good idea at the time."  Thanks once again, we're close. Still hunting the term. Collins version is closer to this mysterious word that I encountered. Best.